# IIS Re-write module not working for default document request

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying to use the IIS rewrite module to redirect HTTP to HTTPS for certain areas of my site.

It works mostly. However I've noticed a strange inconsistency if the request uses the default document.

For example...

http://[mydomain]/test_folder/default.aspx

correctly redirects to...

https://[mydomain]/test_folder/default.aspx

However, this URL...

http://[mydomain]/test_folder/

does not redirect.

My re-write rules are defined as follows...

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{SCRIPT_NAME}" pattern="^/(?:admin|test_).*" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

My default documents are defined as follows...

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="default.asp" />
    <add value="default.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

It's like having processed the request for the default document, it doesn't bother to process my rewrite rules.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong, and how to resolve it?

Update: I've been able to work around the problem by removing the rewrite rules, and instead doing the redirection in global.asax. This seems like a slightly hacky way to do it though, so I would prefer to use IIS rewrite if there is a proper solution.

Comment: Your Rewrite rule looks fine, however I'm wondering about the subexpression `(?:admin|test_)`. I tend to always redirect the entire website from HTTP to HTTPS and use: `<rule name="Redirect-HTTP-HTTPS-IIS">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>`

Comment: Thanks @JanReilink I would prefer to be able to just run the site at HTTPS only, but can't due to client requirements. I'm fairly sure the issue I'm encountering must be a limitation of the rewrite module. It obviously isn't called for default document requests. Using global.asax works perfectly for all requests, so I'll just continue doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This rule will redirect all requests which stars with `admin` or `test_`:

```
<rule name="redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(admin|test_)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"/>
</rule>
```

Example:

`http://[mydomain]/test_folder/default.aspx` to `https://[mydomain]/test_folder/default.aspx`
`http://[mydomain]/admin/default.aspx` to `https://[mydomain]/admin/default.aspx`
`http://[mydomain]/test_folder/` to `https://[mydomain]/test_folder/`